# Как в проекте реализовать лицензии

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Использую в проекте аутентификацию по примеру [metanit.com](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/12.1.php)
Как мне реализовать что-то типа лицензий. Например, разрешено пользоваться онлайн не более 5 пользователей и 6-го не пустит. Я так понимаю копать надо в направлении по работе с сессиями? Где можно почитать доходчиво по этим вопросам?

Comment: Я вас разочарую: увы, нигде. Ни на русском нет глубокого описания (хабр, метаинт, профессорвеб), ни на английском: перечитал в своё время все официальные статьи, они все банальные и вводного уровня. (Каждый новый автор не смотрит, что пишут другие и поэтому каждый раз описывает всё с нуля и останавливается когда материала наберёт на страничку текста. Раздражает.) Поэтому можете смотреть исходники identity, там всё банально -- но реализовывать придётся самостоятельно.

Comment: Да, гуглил и на английском. Не нашел инфу=)